# Limit function in Kotlin

Tags: java-8, java-stream, kotlin

There is a stream method `limit` in Java 8:

```
package com.concretepage.util.stream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class LimitDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE");    
        list.stream().limit(3).forEach(s->System.out.println(s));
    }        
}
```

output:

```
AA
BB
CC
```

What is the name of analog in Kotlin, or how to do it better by another way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr

Comment: If you view the API reference you can see extension functions on collections, which include the answer.  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html, other collection docs are new at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html):

```
list.take(3).forEach(::System.out.println)
```

Comment: You can even write `::println`