# Lazy stream operations and unresolved reference for stream()

Tags: java, java-stream, kotlin

I'm developing some log analyzing tool with kotlin. I have a large amount of incoming logs so it impossible to load them all into the memory, I need to process them in "pipeline" manner.
And I found out two things disappointing me:

1. As I understand all stream-like methods for kotlin collections (`filter`, `map` and so on) are not lazy. E.g. I have 1 GB of logs and want to get lengths of first ten lines that are matches the given regexp. If I write it as is, filtering and transforming will be applied to whole gigabyte of strings in memory.
2. I can't write `l.stream()`, where l defined as `val l = ArrayList<String>()`. Compiler says: "Unresolved reference: stream".

So the questions are: are you going to make collection functions lazy? And why can't I access the `stream()` method?

Comment: `stream()` equivalents in Kotlin:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Kotlin does not use Java 8 Streams, instead there is lazy [`Sequence<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html). It has API mostly unified with `Iterable<T>`, so you can learn more about its usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr).

   `Sequence<T>` is similar to `Stream<T>`, but it offers more when it comes to sequential data (e.g. `takeWhile`), though it has no parallel operations support at the moment*.

   Another reason for introducing a replacement for Stream API is that Kotlin targets Java 6, which has no Streams, so they [were dropped](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/kotlin-evolves-how-to-keep-your-code-up/) from Kotlin stdlib in favor of `Sequence<T>`.
2. A `Sequence<T>` can be created from an `Iterable<T>` (which every `Collection<T>` is) with [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) method:

   ```
   val l = ArrayList<String>()
   val sequence = l.asSequence()
   ```

   This is equivalent to `.stream()` in Java and will let you process a collection lazily. Otherwise, transformations are eagerly applied to a collection.

---

<sub>* If you need it, the workaround is to rollback to Java 8 Streams:</sub>

`(collection as java.lang.Collection<T>).parallelStream()`