# How to remove duplicate strings from an array in Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

How to remove duplicates from an `Array<String?>` in Kotlin?

Comment: If someone is looking for consecutive characters to remove then visit
https://handyopinion.com/method-to-remove-consecutive-characters-from-a-string-in-kotlin-android/

Answer (score 341, accepted):

Use the [`distinct` extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html):

```
val a = arrayOf("a", "a", "b", "c", "c")
val b = a.distinct() // ["a", "b", "c"]
```

There's also [`distinctBy` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html) that allows one to specify how to distinguish the items:

```
val a = listOf("a", "b", "ab", "ba", "abc")
val b = a.distinctBy { it.length } // ["a", "ab", "abc"]
```

As [@mfulton26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255152/mfulton26) suggested, you can also use [`toSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-set.html), [`toMutableSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-set.html) and, if you don't need the original ordering to be preserved, [`toHashSet`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-hash-set.html). These functions produce a `Set` instead of a `List` and should be a little bit more efficient than `distinct`.

---

You may find useful:

- [Kotlin idioms](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html)
- [What Java 8 Stream.collect equivalents are available in the standard Kotlin library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr)

Comment: You can also use `toSet` or `toMutableSet` which have less overhead than `distinct` and if ordering does not matter you can use `toHashSet`.

Comment: @mfulton26, certainly it doesn't always have overhead. E.g. a JPA entity object can have lazy loaded fields, so it's more efficient to distinct its collection by id than perform full comparison

Comment: @Buckstabue if you only need a Collection back (and it doesn't matter if it is a List or a Set) then using a Collection optimized for unique elements will be more efficient. The current implementation of distinct uses toMutableSet() in its implementation and then converts it to a List so by using toSet et. al. directly you avoid the extra intermediary Collection instance ([kotlin/_Arrays.kt:9145-9155 at master · JetBrains/kotlin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/90c787e1023554bd0bc435071a78b9986f001068/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Arrays.kt#L9148-L9155)).

Comment: @mfulton26, please re-read my comment. I said "it is NOT ALWAYS efficient" and gave you an example where .distinctBy{  } can be useful. Sometimes calling equals() and hashCode() is a very expensive thing

Comment: @Buckstabue I see, I believe we're talking about two different issues: 1) `to*Set` is more efficient (space & time) than `distinct[By]` because it returns the `Set` directly instead of using a `Set` internally and converting it to a `List` as its return value and 2) `distinctBy` is can be more efficient than `distinct` simply because you can avoid full object equality comparison. Both are valid points. I ran with your statement that "certainly it doesn't always have overhead" and I was replying to that and overlooked that you were comparing `distinct` with `distinctBy` (and not with `to*Set`).

Comment: @mfulton26, you are correct. I mostly meant that sometimes it's better to use List + distinctBy than Set, because Set intensively use equals/hashCode which potentially might be expensive to call

Comment: At time of writing, `Iterable.distinct` actually does `toMutableSet().toList()` internally. So don't worry about performance :-)

Comment: @Luke, using `.toHashSet()` should be a little faster than `.toMutableSet()` or `.toSet()`, as those create a linked hash set, which has additional links between the elements, consuming a little more time to construct than an ordinary hash set. And also, `.toHashSet()` or `.toSet()` don't spend time converting the result back to a list. But except for hot, performance-critical code, the difference should be negligible.

Comment: Please note that `distinct` or `toSet` won't work on a list of arrays. I.e List of ByteArray or List of CharArray

Comment: @aldok That's because `distinct` and `toSet` rely on `equals` for comparison and arrays don't implement `equals` (they just inherit it form `Object` which uses `==` for equality). I.e. arrays are only equal if they refer to the same array object. You could use `distinctBy { it.toList() }` as a quick solution, but that converts the arrays to lists, then the list of lists to a set, which compares the lists by contents and removes duplicates, and then converts the set back to a list, so it's probably not the most effective way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithm

If you need to remove duplicates in-place use the following extension function:

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> Array<T?>.distinctInPlace(): Int {
    this.sortBy { it }
    var placed = 1
    var removed = 0
    var i = 1
    while (i < size) {
        if (this[i] == this[i - 1])
            removed++
        else {
            this[placed] = this[i]
            placed++
        }
        i++
    }
    for (iter in size - removed..lastIndex)
        this[iter] = null
    return size - removed
}
```

This method will return the amount of unique elements in O(n log(n)) time. All of them will be sorted. Last `for` loop is used to set all other elements to `null`.

Note: if you had a `null` element in the array, it will be placed at the 0 index - so you can distinguish whether you had any `null`s or they were added after.

### Examples

```
fun main() {
    val arr = arrayOf("a", null, "b", null, "c", "ab", "ab")
    arr.distinctInPlace() // returns 5, arr is now [null, "a", "ab", "b", "c", null, null]

    val withoutNulls = arrayOf("a", "a", "aa", "aaa", "aa")
    withoutNulls.distinctInPlace() // returns 3, arr is now ["a", "aa", "aaa"]
}
```