# Android Kotlin how to Remove duplicate values in a list

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, spinner

I am trying to get JSON data into a spinner.

```
val product_sizes = productfeed.variants.joinToString { variants -> variants.option_values[0].name }
    Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${product_sizes} ")
```

this is the output:

> TESTING:: SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, 1 XL, 2 XL, 3 XL, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, 1 XL, 2 XL, 3 XL, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, 1 XL, 2 XL, 3 XL, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, 1 XL, 2 XL, 3 XL, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, 1 XL, 2 XL, 3 XL

I want to get only one set of the sizes into a spinner not 5 of them.
I have also tried:

```
 val product_sizes = productfeed.variants.joinToString { variants -> variants.option_values[0].name.toSet().toList().toString() }
    Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${product_sizes} ")
```

The output was:

> TESTING:: [S, M, A, L], [M, E, D, I, U], [L, A, R, G, E], [1,  , X, L], [2,  , X, L], [3,  , X, L], [S, M, A, L], [M, E, D, I, U], [L, A, R, G, E], [1,  , X, L], [2,  , X, L], [3,  , X, L], [S, M, A, L], [M, E, D, I, U], [L, A, R, G, E], [1,  , X, L], [2,  , X, L], [3,  , X, L], [S, M, A, L], [M, E, D, I, U], [L, A, R, G, E], [1,  , X, L], [2,  , X, L], [3,  , X, L], [S, M, A, L], [M, E, D, I, U], [L, A, R, G, E], [1,  , X, L], [2,  , X, L], [3,  , X, L]

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: What was the idea behind `toSet().toList().toString()`?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430297/kotlin-idiomatic-way-to-remove-duplicate-strings-from-array

Comment: I was looking for a solution and the toSet().toList().toString() came up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the list to a `Set` before you join, not after

```
val product_sizes = productfeed.variants
                               .map { it.option_values[0].name }
                               .toSet()
                               .joinToString()
Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${product_sizes} ")
```

The output then will be

> TESTING:: SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, 1 XL, 2 XL, 3 XL

You can also use [`distincBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html) to omit a `map` operator.

```
val product_sizes = productfeed.variants
                               .distincBy { it.option_values[0].name }
                               .joinToString { it.option_values[0].name }
Log.d("TAG", "TESTING:: ${product_sizes} ")
```