# How can I filter an ArrayList in Kotlin so I only have elements which match my condition?

Tags: list, kotlin, filtering

I have an array:

```
var month: List<String> = arrayListOf("January", "February", "March")
```

I have to filter the list so I am left with only `"January"`.

Comment: Please clarify the question that you want "January" filtered OUT of the list (removed) or filter the list to ONLY have "January"  ... The question is being interpreted in the answers in a way that seems opposite of what makes sense.

Comment: It is a good idea for new Kotlin developers to scan the STDLIB API reference guide so you have an idea of what is available for use.  http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html  And if coming from Java 8 streams, you can get an idea of equivalents in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-java-8-stream-collect-equivalents-are-available-in-the-standard-kotlin-libr

Comment: I needed to filter out the month January. I have edited the question

Comment: filter in, or filter out?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can use this code to filter out January from array, by using this code

```
var month: List<String> = arrayListOf("January", "February", "March")
// to get the result as list
var monthList: List<String> = month.filter { s -> s == "January" }

// to get a string
var selectedMonth: String = month.filter { s -> s == "January" }.single()
```

Comment: Note that in Kotlin you do not have to use `.equals` explicitly. It would be more idiomatic to just use `==` which will do the right thing.

Comment: this is the opposite of the request, they want to remove "January" from the list not keep only January, please update the answer to be correct, otherwise the accepted answer should be moved to answer from zsmb13 which covers both cases.

Comment: You can simplify it even further with: `month.single { s -> s == "January" }`

Comment: How would this change if you had a list of custom Objects, and not just some built-in type like Int, or String?

Comment: Even shorter `month.single { it == "January" }`

Comment: How can I show the list Item "January", when I type only "J"?

Answer (score 46):

There are a number of functions for filtering collections, if you want to keep only values matching `"January"`, you can use the simple [`filter()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html):

```
val months = listOf("January", "February", "March")

months.filter { month -> month == "January" } // with explicit parameter name
months.filter { it == "January" }             // with implicit parameter name "it"
```

These will give you a list containing only `"January"`.

If you want all months that are *not* `"January"`, you can either reverse the condition using `!=`, or use [`filterNot()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not.html):

```
months.filter { it != "January" }
months.filterNot { it == "January" }
```

These will give you a list containing `"February"` and `"March"`.

Note that unlike Java, using the `==` and `!=` operators in Kotlin is actually the same as calling the `equals` function on the objects. For more, see the docs about [equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html).

For the complete list of collection functions in the standard library, see the [API reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html#functions).

Comment: How would I filter out multiple values? Say, I would like both "January" and "March" filtered out of the list?

Comment: You could do something like `months.filter { it !in listOf("January", "March" }`.

Answer (score 28):

You want to filter this list of Strings containing months.

```
var month : List<String> = arrayListOf("January", "February", "March")
```

You can use [`filterNot()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not.html) method of list. It returns a list containing all elements except the given predicate.

```
var filteredMonthList : List<String> = month.filterNot { s -> s == "January" }
// results:  ["February", "March"]
```

You can use [`filter()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) method of list. It returns a list containing all elements matching the given predicate.

```
var filteredMonthList : List<String> = month.filter { s -> s == "January" }
// results:  ["January"]
```

After `filter()` if we use [`single()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html) method then it will return a single value and throw an exception if more than one value is in the list.

```
var filteredMonth : String = month.filter { s -> s == "January" }.single()
// result:  "January"
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what was asked.

Comment: The question asks to filter the month, which means to remove it.  You do the opposite and filter everything BUT the month.  The question should be worded a bit more clearly as "filter out the month"

Comment: @JaysonMinard Please check the answer now.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Thanks. The answer is looking awesome.

Answer (score 12):

I am just sharing that if you have **custom list** and check whether it is **null or blank** you can check in Kotlin in single line
Just do it like that

```
  fun filterList(listCutom: List<Custom>?) {
    var fiterList = listCutom!!.filter { it.label != "" }
    //Here you can get the list which is not having any kind of lable blank
  }
```

You can check multiple conditions also

```
 fun filterList(listCutom: List<Custom>?) {
    var fiterList = listCutom!!.filter { it.label != "" && it.value != ""}
    //Here you can get the list which is not having any kind of lable or value blank
  }
```

Note : I am assuming that **label & value** are the variables of **Custom** Model class.

Comment: What is label is boolean and still we want to check if that label is present in list or not? Don't want to go for default case.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [find](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html) or `findLast`. This is specifically meant to return only one value instead of a list of `String` returned in case of `filter`.

```
var month = arrayListOf("January", "February", "March")
var result = month.find { s -> s == "January" }
```

Answer (score 5):

**Filtering by predicate**

```
    val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four")
    var items: List<String> = numbers.filter { s -> s == "one" }

    var item = numbers.singleOrNull { it == "one" }

    if (item != null) {
        print("FOUND:$item")
    } else {
        print("Not FOUND!")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = list.filter {
            if (it.user.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                return@filter false
            } else if (!it.user.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                return@filter it.user != "guardian"
            }
            return@filter false
        }
```

Comment: Please explain how that works and why it solves the problem.

Comment: It returns list which item return with @filter true i.e the condition match items list will return from list.filter{ }

Comment: Please [edit] that into the answer itself, to turn it from a code-only answer into an explained answer. Try for [answer].